# Microsoft Resource File To COFF Object Conversion Utility has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Whenever I open a Visual Studio project 2010 or 2012 I get

> Microsoft Resource File To COFF Object Conversion Utility has stopped working

What I tried so far

1. System File Checker tool (SFC.exe)  sfc /scannow   **I get no errors**
2. Removed any files from %temp%
3. Googled and everybody suggests the above and many posts says that they could not get rid of it.
4. Reinstalling vs2010 and vs2012 didn't help.

Comment: did you *Run as administrator*?

Comment: Type "where cvtres.exe" at the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  If you have the full version of VS then you'll find two of them, one in the vc/bin subdirectory, another in the .NET framework directory.  Your question is way too poorly documented to judge which one might cause the problem and whether the .exe is damaged or it just fails on bad resource data.  EXE damage points to a much bigger problem, disk corruption.

Comment: @Alex Yes I did run as admistrator.@HansPassant I could not document anymore because I dont have more to give.What can I give?

Comment: Try to do a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Project Settings->Linker->General->Enable Incremental Linking->No.